# update one table from another selected table

Tags: sql-server

I select one column from a table and generated the second column by `select case`:

```
(select Id , case
when education=0 then '0::ALL'
when education=1 then '1::HIGH_SCHOOL'
when education=2 then '2::UNDERGRAD'
when education=3 then '3::ALUM'
when education=4 then '4::HIGH_SCHOOL_GRAD'
when education=5 then '5::SOME_COLLEGE'
when education=6 then '6::ASSOCIATE_DEGREE'
when education=7 then '7::IN_GRAD_SCHOOL'
when education=8 then '8::SOME_GRAD_SCHOOL'
when education=9 then '9::MASTER_DEGREE'
when education=10 then '10::PROFESSIONAL_DEGREE'
when education=11 then '11::DOCTORATE_DEGREE'
when education=12 then '12::UNSPECIFIED'
end as myeducation
from ids_table where Id = '4fcc-a519-15db04651b91')
```

assuming it returns:

```
------------------------------------------------
|         Id                 myeducation       |
|  4fcc-a519-15db04651b91,   9::MASTER_DEGREE  |
------------------------------------------------
```

in the same table (ids_table), I have an empty column is called: allEducations

I want to set allEducations = myeducation where id (of the table above that I "created") is equal to the id of the table (ids_table)

before:

```
ids_table:
  ----------------------------------------------
|         Id                 allEducation       |
|  4fcc-a519-15db04651b91,                      |
------------------------------------------------
```

after:

```
  ----------------------------------------------
|         Id                   allEducation     |
|  4fcc-a519-15db04651b91,   9::MASTER_DEGREE   |
------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to do something like:

```
`;WITH b AS (THE SQL QUERY ABOVE) update ids_table c set c.allEducations = b.myeducation where c.id = b.id'
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
begin tran updateEducation

update ids_table set allEducations = 
    case
    when education=0 then '0::ALL'
    when education=1 then '1::HIGH_SCHOOL'
    when education=2 then '2::UNDERGRAD'
    when education=3 then '3::ALUM'
    when education=4 then '4::HIGH_SCHOOL_GRAD'
    when education=5 then '5::SOME_COLLEGE'
    when education=6 then '6::ASSOCIATE_DEGREE'
    when education=7 then '7::IN_GRAD_SCHOOL'
    when education=8 then '8::SOME_GRAD_SCHOOL'
    when education=9 then '9::MASTER_DEGREE'
    when education=10 then '10::PROFESSIONAL_DEGREE'
    when education=11 then '11::DOCTORATE_DEGREE'
    when education=12 then '12::UNSPECIFIED'
    end

---- if it is not good
-- rollback 

---- if it is good
-- commit
```